# Temporarily close triage review queue for user when 0 flags remaining

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

When a user has 0 flags remaining, I think they should be temporarily blocked from reviewing posts in the *Triage* queue until they have at least 1 flag left.

Let's say a user has 0 flags remaining but still wants to continue reviewing posts and comes across a post that should really be marked as "Unsalvageable" - they may be more inclined to chose either "Looks OK" or "Requires Editing" rather than "Unsalvageable" as they are no longer able to actually choose the "Unsalvageable" option with no flags remaining.

Obviously in this scenerio one should skip the question (or wait to continue reviewing another time when they have flags remaining), but I think that it might be worth temporarily closing the *Triage* review queue for that user to prevent the possibility of their reviewing being influenced by them having no flags left.

Comment: Have you met my friend Skip? They're great. When there are no options are applicable to the post, just choose Skip. After a while, you and Skip will be friends too.

Comment: I know, I know - I mentioned that in the post. My point is that I have a feeling that not everyone will just Skip (as they feel they are wasting their time) and may be more inclined to choose Requires Editing instead of choosing Skip as they should.

Comment: Yeah, but those that would choose Skip get kicked out of review so that those that wouldn't choose Skip don't make the wrong decision? That doesn't make much sense to me. Any change has to be a user education or user interaction change. For example, if you're worried about people favoring other options over Skip, why not suggest changing the skip button to a primary color associated with making people want to click it? (as a naive example) ...

Comment: Sure, I see what you're saying. It might be worth it to have a notice appear when 0 flags are remaining like "You've reached your limit of flagging posts for now - if you see a post that should be marked Unsalvageable please skip it. Otherwise wait until you have more flags remaining to continue reviewing." or something along those lines.

Comment: ... You could, for example, suggest that users who don't have flags are only shown posts that the system has identified as "borderline" (im sure the posts that the system automatically pushes into review have a given score), enabling them to see more posts that are in need of positive review instead of negative review.

Comment: The banner idea is alright, could use some fleshing out. I'm sure a good suggestion can be made for some kind of user education change in this regard.